# How do I check if my double field is filled in on a GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, double, jtextfield

Hey guys I'm currently having some issues making my program work correctly through it's GUI. I have three textfields which the user inputs "Firstname, Lastname, and Mass) Mass is a double and I'm trying to make the program tell the user when the field is not filled in properly. Because mass is a double I can't use ("") like i did previously for the name fields. I've tried several things so far.

```
if (Double.parseDouble(EnterMass.getText()) {
        TransactionDisplay.setText("There is a field which isn't filled in \nPlease fill in all fields then try again");     
        return;
    }
```

was my most recent attempt but it tells me double cannot be converted to boolean. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To choose the `JTextField`:

    ...
    private JTextField EnterMass = new JTextField();
    
    ...
    if (!EnterMass.getText().isEmpty()) {
      return Double.parseDouble(EnterMass.getText());
    } else {
      TransactionDisplay.setText("There is a field which isn't filled in \nPlease fill in all fields then try again"); 
    };

Answer (score 0):

> try this.try to look first if field is not empty before u get the value

```
if(EnterMass.getText().isEmpty())

{

  TransactionDisplay.setText("There is a field which isn't filled in \nPlease fill in all fields then try again");    

  return null;

}

else{

return Double.parseDouble(EnterMass.getText());

}
```